# Google maps api v3 - Events

Tags: google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3

How to run a function after google maps loaded all needed DOM-Elements?

I wrote some jquery to give the controls a new position,
now i need the best point to run this function.

As soon as possible, right after the controls are inside the DOM.

```
_options.map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById( $this.attr('id') ), mapOptions);

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(_options.map, 'idle', function(){
  Query('.gmnoprint:eq(2)').css('left','14%');
});
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
 // do something only the first time the map is loaded
});
```

Comment: tried this, event is fired. but there is no control element avaible at this time.

jQuery('.gmnoprint:eq(2)').css('left','14%');